# I have to press twice C-b in emacs in osx terminal

Tags: macos, emacs

I installed emacs through brew in osx,

everytime I press C-b it doesn't do anything. I have to press it twice every time to make it work once. Any idea?

Comment: Not actually an answer, so submitting as comment.

Why don't you try the emacs available at http://emacsformacosx.com/? I used it daily and differs very little from the emacs on GNU/Linux.

Comment: I need a terminal emacs : o

Comment: Not a problem, just install this emacs and put this line on your .bash_profile `alias emacs="/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs -nw"`. Open your terminal, type "emacs" and you are done.